# ctypes char* pointer needed

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

I have a C function returning strings (char *), let's call it `foo()`.
In python I want to call it and use it's return value, and when I'm done, I want to call an other C function which frees the string `foo` returned.

How can I get both the pointer and the string itself? If I do like this:

```
fooFunc = foolib.foo
fooFunc.restype = c_char_p
r = fooFunc()
```

Then I get the string, but not the pointer. If I do it without specifying the `restype`, I get an int which seems to be the correct address, but whenever I try to cast it to sting with `c_char_p(<address>)` it crashes with segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised you can't just pass back the `c_char_p` instance to the second function, but I don't have the tools at hand to verify why it would fail.

However, as an alternative, I believe you could try:

- Specifying the `restype` as a simple pointer (`c_void_p`)
- When you want to manipulate the string, use [`ctypes.string_at`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.string_at) to build it
- Pass the initially returned pointer to the freeing function.